# "This field may not be empty" - it isn't!

Tags: validation, marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, boolean

I have been trying to add a contact to a data extension in Contact Builder.
I have two boolean fields - REQUIRED fields, called doNotUse and suppressJourney.
The default value of these fields are both set to FALSE.

When trying to change it to true, or even picking 'false' from the dropdown when adding a record, I get an alert saying 'this field may not be empty.' It isn't empty! I am trying to add a value to it - true or false - and it won't let me save the record, rendering my data extension totally useless, as these fields are used to control contacts' entrance into a journey. Does anyone know what is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest opening a support case.

As a work-around, you can export the data, fix the values in the file and re-import it.

Also, make liberal use of the Feedback button at the top of the page.  They need to hear about these bugs.

[image: feedback all the things]

Comment: Thanks - wasn't sure if it was something I was doing wrong elsewhere but it does seem that this is a bug!

Comment: The UX team will likely push you to open a support ticket, but you should let them know what a terrible UX experience it is editing rows in a Data Extension.

Comment: You're not wrong!